# Determining initial conditions for a simple circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

Suppose the circuit is in steady state when the switch is at position (1). At t=0 the switch goes from position (1) to position (2)and the problem is to find the response of the system. I am having some difficulties finding the initial value for the voltage on the capacitor. Since it was stated that we can assume it is in steady state for t<0, I solved it in the phasor domain and got that the rms value of Uc=7.01V. Can I somehow use this for the actual initial value(in the time domain). Data given:

- R = 10,
- L=10 mH,
- C=100 uF,
- E = 10V,
- e(t)=14.1*sin(1000t+ 135(deg)).

**EDIT** I see a lot of arguments in the comments below, and one question that basically repeats what is said in the question. I would be very grateful if someone could give a concise answer, how to solve it, and if it is not possible, why it is not possible.
**EDIT 2** Thanks to everyone who was active in the comments section, and who answered. I will award the best answer. Basically, the easiest way is to solve the circuit in the phasor domain, reconstruct the equations for the time domain, and just plug in the value for t=0, since we are viewing the system for t=\$-\infty\$ to t=\$\infty\$

Comment: The initial voltage of the capacitor `C` depends on the function of the voltage source `e(t)`. Please specify it in your question.

Comment: @MartinZabel it is specified.

Comment: @MartinZabel I did

Comment: @Andyaka, @Shemafied  Sorry, missed it. So then, what should be the steady state of `e(t)` before `t<0`? Zero voltage?

Comment: The RMS voltage on C is 7.05V and not 7.01V

Comment: @Andyaka oh come on

Comment: Am I missing a joke or something, maybe I have something between my teeth?

Comment: I'm trying to help by being accurate because, as you might learn when you stop being a child, accuracy is very important.

Comment: The circuit has attained sinusoidal steady state before switching. Substituting t=0 in sine function would mean that the transients have not died down. You can't find the instantaneous value of capacitor at the moment of switching unless you know the value of variable 't' of sine function.

Comment: @Shemafied, as I mentioned above, it's not possible to solve this problem because the instantaneous voltage of sine source and hence the instantaneous voltage across capacitor is unknown at the moment of switching.

Comment: @Aditya Patil, see answer, below

Comment: @Chu What you've calculated is not the instantaneous value.

Comment: @AdityaPatil, it's the value at t=0, when the system has been in steady state, clearly it's the capacitor voltage when the switch is operated at t=0

Comment: @Chu t=0 is just a way of representing that some transition has occurred in the circuit at some time. 'At t=0 the switch has just been moved to position 2' simply means that at some instant(which is represented as t=0), switch's position is changed. If we were to substitute t=0 (as you're doing) in the function of source, it would mean that the circuit has not reached steady state.

Comment: @Aditya Patil, no, it means that the sinusoid has been going since \$t=-\infty\$, then at t=0 the switch is operated.

Comment: @Chu You may say so. I think you're right.  I considered it purely from physical and mathematical angle, but not from logical angle as you've rightly done!

Comment: @Andyaka I'm stuck. Could you help me out here?

Comment: @Aditya Patil, yes, all functions of time exist for negative t unless specified as unilateral. \$sin(t)\$ is as valid at t=-1 as it is at t=1

Comment: I suggest to clarify in the question, that **sinusodial** steady state is reached before t=0.

Comment: @Shemafied: what's not correct and/or not concise with my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would be very grateful if someone could give a concise answer, how
>   to solve it, and if it is not possible, why it is not possible.

It is possible.  For \$t \lt 0\$, the switch is in position 1 and you have a series RC circuit in sinusoidal steady state.

The phasor voltage across the capacitor in a series RC circuit is given by:

$$V_c(\omega) = V_s\frac{1}{1 + j\omega RC} = V_s \frac{e^{i\phi}}{\sqrt{1 + (\omega RC)^2}}$$

where \$\tan \phi = -\omega RC\$.

In the case of the circuit in your question

$$V_s = 10\sqrt{2}\;e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}$$

$$\omega RC = 1$$

Before the switch changes state, the RC circuit is in steady state and so

$$V_c = 10\sqrt{2}\;e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}}}{\sqrt{1 + 1}} = 10\mathrm V$$

Converting to the time domain, the capacitor voltage is then

$$v_C(t) = 10\mathrm V \cos(1000\cdot t)\;, t \le 0$$

and thus the capacitor voltage, just before the switch changes state is

$$v_C(0-) = 10 \cos(0-) = 10 \mathrm V $$

Since the voltage across a capacitor cannot instantaneously change (for finite current through), the voltage across the capacitor just *after* the switch changes state is unchanged.

$$v_C(0+) = v_C(0-) = 10\mathrm V $$

This is the initial capacitor voltage that is required to find the solution for \$t \gt 0\$

Comment: Isn't the rms value actually 10/sqrt(2)? By defintion it should be less than the amplitude in the t-domain-

Comment: @Shemafied, it's true that the rms value of \$10 \cos (1000t)\$ is \$10 / \sqrt{2} \$ but why do you want the rms value of the capacitor voltage?  By the way, and if it isn't clear, I'm using peak phasors in my calculation rather than rms phasors

Comment: That's what caused the confusion.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, note that \$\small 14.1\$ is probably \$\small 10\sqrt 2\$.

At \$\small \omega=1000\$ rad/sec, \$\small X_C=-j10\$. Hence, the voltage across the capacitor, relative to a sinusoidal voltage source of amplitude \$\small 10\sqrt2\$, but with zero phase angle, \$\small \phi = 0^o\$, would be:

\$\small V_C=10\sqrt2\:\dfrac{-j10}{10-j10}= 10\sqrt 2\:\dfrac{-j}{1-j}=10\sqrt 2\:\dfrac{1-j}{2} \equiv 10\:\large\angle\small{-45^o}\$.

However, the source actually has a phase angle, \$\small \phi=135^o\$, hence the actual \$\small V_C\$ is:

\$\small V_C=10\:\large\angle\small (135-45)=10\:\large \angle\small {90^o}\$.

Thus, when \$\small t=0\$, the capacitor voltage is: \$\small V_C=10\:sin(90^o)=10V\$, which is the required initial condition.

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to know the RMS (or the amplitiude) of the capacitor voltage as it does **not** tell you the voltage exact at the moment the switch is changed (t=0) but only the average over time (or the maximum).

If you want to use phasor domain analysis to find the initial condition of the capacitor you can still use it: you must also use the **phase angel**. Together with the amplitude it tells you the momentary voltage at t=0.

Comment: So you suggest to solve the circuit( pos(1)) using the classical approach, and then just use whatever values I get at t=0 as my initial conditions. Is it even possible to solve the part for (1) since we don't have the initial charge on the capacitor at t=$\-infty$, or do we just assume it is zero?

Comment: @Shemafied
"and then just use whatever values I get at t=0 as my initial conditions."

No. t=0 is just a way of representing state of the circuit at the moment of switching. It has nothing to do with the sinusoidal function.

Comment: @Aditya Patil, no, you're wrong, the 't' in the sinusoid is the same 't' as in the initial condition, t=0.

Comment: @Chu It most certainly is not. That's what I've been trying to explain. If 't' in the sinusoid is the same 't' as in the initial condition, it would imply that the circuit has not attained steady state!

Comment: @Aditya Patil, it most certainly is. There is only one 't' in the question. That value of t defines the horizontal axis of the sine wave, and when t=0 on that horizontal axis, the switch is moved to position 2. Tell me where in the question it says that t in the sine wave is not related to t in the switch.

Comment: I'd ask you the same. Where in the question it says that t in the sine wave IS related to t in the switch.

Comment: There is only one letter t in the equations! We have two expressions: \$t=0\$ and \$e(t)=14.1 sin(1000t +135^o)\$, why would you think they refer to different times? Apart from anything else, the question wouldn't make sense with your interpretation.

Comment: As I've been saying, t=0 is just representing the switching. There is absolutely no reason to substitute the same in sine function.

Comment: I'm finished, my head hurts.

Comment: @AdityaPatil, it doesn't need to be said since it is understood that \$t\$ *is* the time parameter by almost everyone familiar with these types of problems.  The source voltage is specified as a sinusoidal function of the time parameter \$t\$ where \$-\infty \lt t \lt \infty\$.  For this problem, the switch has been in position 1 for all time before \$t=0\$ and is in position 2 for all time after \$t=0\$.

Comment: @Aditya Pati: Of course the t in the sinusoidal and the t in "switch at t=0" must mean the same t. Saying that steady state is attained at t=0 referes only to the C-R part with switch in position 1. Other interpretations of the problem don't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: according to the discussion in the comments, the following applies only for DC steady state.

For me a steady state means that the properties of a system do not change there values with time, i.e, for a property p $$dp/dt=0$$

Thus voltages, currents and the electric charge whithin the capacitance need to be static.

This rule is violated here because the source `e(t)` tries to change the voltage for `t<0`. Thus, there is no steady state while the switch is in position 1 as claimed in the question.

(Hence why I asked in the comments below the question.)

Comment: t can be negative!

Comment: @Chu Yes of course. It has no impact on my answer. Point `t=0` is just the moment when the switch is changed to position 2.

Comment: it's also the time when the sinusoid is \$14.1sin(0 +135^o)\$. There is only one time, t, in the question.

Comment: No, the circuit is operating in sinusoidal steady state. Steady state does not strictly mean 'not changing with time'. The steady state here refers to the state attained after transients have died down.

Comment: Steady state means the sinusoid has been established for a long time and the currents and voltages in the circuit have reached their respective constant amplitudes and phase angles. It does not mean the circuit is at DC steady state. Look at the circuit diagram - with the switch in position 1 the sine voltage is applied to the R/C series circuit for a long time. You are misinterpreting 'steady state' when applied to AC circuits.

Comment: If you apply a sine voltage to a circuit containing passive RLC components the currents and voltages will reach steady state where the amplitudes and phase angles are constant. This is what frequency response is all about - it means STEADY STATE frequency response

Comment: So are you saying that the RMS value is constant but the amplitude is not?

Comment: @AdityaPatil Ok, "sinusodial steady state" is new to me. But, then Chu will be right I think. My PSpice simulation also showed me that the initial condition of the capacitance is of no relevance.

Comment: @Chu Ok, "sinusodial steady state" is new to me. I am agreeing with you now.

Comment: @Chu, I did not read the comments properly. Yes, the amplitude will be constant. Sorry for the trouble. Thank you :)

Comment: @MartinZabel, your definition of steady state is true for DC functions. The complete response of any linear circuit has two parts, the natural response and the forced response. The natural response is the transient response of a circuit to a sudden change in circuit conditions. The forced response is the steady state response of the circuit("voltages/currents in the circuit would have reached their respective constant amplitudes and phase angles", as Chu said) which in this case is sinusoidal.